# Make stty setting permanent

Tags: linux, serial-port, stty

I tried to setup raw serial communication over ttyusb0 and used stty to change baud rate and raw mode. Those settings were successful and it was visible after I checked ttyUSB0 again, so after

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 raw cs8 -cstopb -parenb -icanon min 1 time 1
stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0
```

would give me what I wanted.
But, now Im trying to revert these changes and it's not working.
I set baud rate to 115200 but after restart, it's back to 9600 again.
What may be the problem?

Comment: The thing is, after doing re-instalation on usbserial modul 
http://superuser.com/a/596911/612780

I/m still getting the same values..

Comment: I'm having much the same problem: "stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw" followed by "stty -a -F /dev/ttyUSB0" doesn't appear to be clearing the special character settings to undef.  Holding ttyUSB0 open for read and sleeping doesn't appear to help either.  Doing much the same thing in CPython using tty.setraw(fd, when=termios.TCSANOW) doesn't appear to work either.